# Prevent stemming of words starting with # in PostgreSQL full text search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, stemming

Basically, I want to be able to get an exact match (hashtag included) for queries like this:

```
=#SELECT to_tsvector('english', '#adoption');
 to_tsvector
-------------
 'adopt':1
```

Instead, I want for words starting with #, to see:

```
=#SELECT to_tsvector('english', '#adoption');
 to_tsvector
-------------
 '#adoption':1
```

Is this possible with psql full text search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you search or index, you could replace each `#` character with some other character that you don't use in your texts, but which changes the parser's interpretation:

```
test=> SELECT alias, lexemes FROM ts_debug('english', '#adoption');
┌───────────┬─────────┐
│   alias   │ lexemes │
├───────────┼─────────┤
│ blank     │         │
│ asciiword │ {adopt} │
└───────────┴─────────┘
(2 rows)

test=> SELECT alias, lexemes FROM ts_debug('english', '/adoption');
┌───────┬─────────────┐
│ alias │   lexemes   │
├───────┼─────────────┤
│ file  │ {/adoption} │
└───────┴─────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: Genius -- thanks! Though I wish PSQL would just extend their parser to recognize hashtags. They're used all over...